# CSS Color Overlay PNG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, webkit

I thought that there would be an answer to this but I have not found one.

I have a PNG image with a transparent background. Through CSS I'd like the image (not the transparent background) to change to a different color.

There should be a way to do this through web-kit... but I've heard that that way isn't supported... Is there another way to do it, if not how can I achieve this through web-kit?

For my example, is there a way to change the red ball to a different color...

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/BkFBH/3/

HTML:

```
<img id = "ball" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/p/0/L/e/j/B/red-circle-solid-md.png" width=100 height=100>
```

EDIT:
I need to change in by HEX or RGBA, not hue! But if there is a conversion from HEX to Hue or similar, that could also work!

Thank you all!
-Liam

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tint image using CSS without overlay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546499/tint-image-using-css-without-overlay)

Comment: It's not, I had to clarify the question a bit more...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `hue-rotate` CSS3 filter. Change the `120deg` to your liking.

```
#ball {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(120deg);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BkFBH/4/

Comment: beat me to it :) You can also see other webkit filters in action here - http://codepen.io/rss/pen/ftnDd

Comment: I believe that I should edit my question - I want to be able to enter in a HEX value somewhere and change the circle's color accordingly. Is there a way that I can get the HEX number and then calculate the hue rotation? That may be tough...

Comment: Altering the color in HEX values is not possible with pure CSS, however I asked a similar question myself which uses a php script to do the work. [You can find the question here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17978832/1344955)

Comment: @DJDavid98 That's interesting... I'm not familiar with PHP too much... If I wanted to call that code and edit values in that PHP code using Javascript, would that be possible?

Comment: @LiamShalon You can link it to a specific image (edit `'splat.png'` to the path of the image file relative to the PHP script), upload it to the server, then make a request to `/path/to/script.php?color=00ff00`, and you'll get the image colored green.

Comment: @DJDavid98 I think my question is a duplicate... I just found this awesome way that this one guy did to get the effect I'm looking for... http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/qduSR/1/

Comment: @LiamShalon Yours is not a duplicate of this one, this uses heavy JavaScript, not pure CSS.